# Can connect to SQL Server 2012 but not 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'm not a full-stacker, so forgive me in advance.

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database from a Linux based server (via PHP mssql_connect). I am unable to do so.

The Error we get is:  Connection timed out.

We are able to successfully connect to the SQL Server 2008 r2 from a Windows based server using sqlrv.

I'm able to successfully connect to a SQL Server 2012 database (hosted on Arvixe).

We have FreeTDS installed on our server. The `mssql` module installed and the database credentials added to our freetds.conf -- but still unable to connect.

**We've also been whitelisted to access the database.**

Is there anything we are missing? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get when you can't connect?

Comment: Hi Rick. We get the error of:  Connection timed out.

Comment: [Steps to troubleshoot SQL connectivity issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx). Try connecting first using Windows stack. Then try to apply the article to Linux toolset.

Comment: We were able to connect from a Windows based server, using sqlrv -- but still not able to connect via Linux based server using mssql_connect.

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing IP address from the whitelist. The IP address of the server AND the website needed to be whitelisted.

Also, these IP addresses needed to be allowed to make a remote connection over port 1433 to the database we were attempting to connect to.